# Simplicity of Weyl algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

Let $k$ be a field and let $A_n(k)$ be the $n^\text{th}$ Weyl algebra (i.e. the algebra generated by indeterminates $X_1,\cdots,X_n,Y_1,\cdots,Y_n$ such that $Y_iX_i-X_iY_i = 1$ and everything else commutes).

I read that $A_n(k)$ is simple and I am wondering how one can prove this result.

Looking on Google I only found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895563/showing-the-weyl-algebra-is-simple) on Stackexchange, where the simplicity was proven for the $n=1$ case by an argument using differential operators.

However, for arbitrary $k$, this argument does not work because we cannot use differentiation. Do you know a proof for arbitrary $k$ and $n$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It works the same - see Theorem 2.3 [here](https://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=14027).

Answer (score 0):

Step one prove the normal ordered term like this $\prod_{i}X_i^{\lambda_i}\prod_{j}Y_j^{\sigma_j}$ forms a basis of algebra $A_n$.
Step two check with commutation relations for a polynomial $p:=\sum_{[\lambda],[\sigma]} c_{[\lambda], [\sigma]}\prod_{i}X_i^{\lambda_i}\prod_{j}Y_j^{\sigma_j}$
$$
[Y_i, p] = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_i} p
$$
and
$$
[X_i, p] = -\frac{\partial}{\partial Y_i} p
$$
then we get for any none empty ideal $I\subset A_n$ it contains $1$.